# Adding Pinterest Script Before Closing Body Tag

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

According to the Pinterest website in order to add the Pinterest button to any page I have to add the following just below the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Should I follow the link, grab the script and use wp_enqueue_script?  Or can I somehow include the script element another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function. Pass `$in_footer` argument as `true` and your script will be added before closing body:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pinterest', '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js', array(), false, true);
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: Actually the url gave me a 404 error, but that's exactly what was on the pinterest page.  When I added the fully qualified url it gave me the script.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @jw60660 Don't know, use fully qualified script.